# Redirect requests to testing server for protractor tests

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, e2e-testing

Website that I want to test sends requests to remote address `12.34.56.78:443`. I need to change/mock `12.34.56.78:443` to `45.67.89.10:443`, so that request will go to my testing server, and not the one used by clients. Any idea how I can achieve that with protractor?

I was thinking about mocking requests, but I is there any other idea? And if mocking is the only way, what plugin would you recommend for this?

Comment: This needs more information. Is this the baseUrl? Or is this a test server back end that your web app is making requests against?

Comment: Angular page sends request to back end that calls stored procedures on database and returns data. I need to redirect these requests to my testing server, because my testing database needs to be restored before each test. It is just a HTTP request with server address e.g. xx.xx.xx.xx:443/api/GetUsersCount

Comment: What kind of page is it that you are testing? An AngularJS or Angular?

Comment: @cnishina It's AngularJS